# Replicating elements reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Whenever I try to loop create a range of elements in React.js the screen goes blank and nothing is shown.For example, when I make the function return the element just once, I can display the element as many times as I want by calling the function as shown down below.

[image]

This allows the rest of the content on the page to display as expected, as well as two instances of the element.However, once I loop these elements into an array the page does not display at all.
Loop code:

[image: Loop code]

Page without loop code:

[image: Page without loop code]

Comment: Please include code as text, as well as any error messages shown in the console. There are also multiple tools available for creating snippets of runnable code, including the snippet tool built into the StackOverflow, so if possible, including a small example of the problem will make it much more likely for you to get a good answer.

Comment: could you please console the error

Answer (score 0):

from your program change this

```
function resListing(){
let elements = null;
elements= for(i=0,i<5,i++){
return(
<div className="row list-row">
...rest of the code
</div>
)
}
return(
  {elements}
)
}
```

or
use map function

```
function resListing(){
   return(
   <div>
   Array(5).fill().map((element,index)=>{
  return(
  <div key={index} className="row list-row">
  ...rest of the code
  </div>
 )

 })
 </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using loop then you should have to return new object as new key from function,

1.In render call Function

```
 return(
      getNewElement()
   )
```

2.Use increment varaible as key and return JSX element with unique key

```
function getNewElement(){
   for(let i = 0; i<5 ; i++){
     return(<div key={`div_${i}`}>Hello buddy</div>)
   }
}
```